# Как подключить пользовательские стили и скрипты к DLE?

Tags: html, dle, css

Здравствуйте.

Столкнулся с очень "тупой" проблемой. Сначала написал сайт "в блокноте", потом решил натянуть на какой нибудь движок (ДЛЕ), т.к. уже работал с ним. Подключает стили, только если они лежат в папке style (мучился 7 часов, случайно понял), если не лежат в этой папке, он их не подключит. Скрипты только если лежат в папке js, и то не всегда. (Картинки, которые через джава, скрипт вообще не подключает (стрелочки, кнопочки). Картинки вроде подключает через одну.

Что мне делать?  Может быть из за версии 9.3? Или что-то не так в .htaccess? Но они везде лежат. Помогите, пожалуйста, я думаю, причина очень простая, но почему-то я не могу её обнаружить.

Спасибо.

Comment: бред какой то... у кого какие мысли по этому поводу есть??

Comment: help!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы подключить картинки, пишете

```
<img src="{THEME}/img1.jpg" />
```

Чтобы подключить скрипты, пишете

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{THEME}/js/jcarousellite.js"></script>
```

Чтобы подключить стили, пишете

```
<link media="screen" href="{THEME}/style/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Comment: :) я вкурсе...но это увы не работает

Comment: Причина кроеться в чем то другом...
Если скрипт подключен например :
<script type="text/javascript" src="{THEME}/js/jcarousellite.js"></script>
И если я хочу подключить еще один скрипт например
<script type="text/javascript" src="{THEME}/js/jcarousellite2.js"></script>

То мне нужно его вставить в коде HTML после уже подключенного скрипта1
иначе он не прочитает его...
КАКОЙТО БРЕД

Comment: Такое часто случается у меня тоже. )

Comment: Я подозреваю, что может в денвере не выставлены права на папку?

Comment: Но опять же папка локальная, какие могут быть права...

Comment: И то верно)